# Microsoft Access 2007 - Query Unique Row and display all corresponding fields without using Group by

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, distinct-values

This is for Microsoft Access 2007.

I just have one table -

```
F1  F2  F3
1   A    B
1   A    B
1   A    B
2   C    B
2   C    B
```

I want my query to display unique F1 rows only with F2 & F3 , and also showing count in the last column, F4. 'Group by' does not work because F2 and F3 are not always in the same format. So basically, I want to query unique F1 rows and just display whatever is in F2 and F3 for that row. Thanks in advance.

RESULT:

```
F1  F2  F3  F4
1   A    B   3
2   C    B   2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to display "whatever is in F2 and F3 for that row" because you don't have a single row when you do an aggregation.  Perhaps this solves your needs:

```
select F1, min(F2) as F2, min(F3) as F3, count(*) as F4
from t
group by F1
```

You can also use `first()` and `last()` to get the values from the first and last rows, respectively.

Comment: hmm i think this worked. i am double checking my data right now. its got 1000+ entries. But I have a question - if F3 contained 00-1 and 001, what would min function return? 00-1 or 001?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use an aggregate function `COUNT()` to count the number of records per group.

```
SELECT  F1, F2, F3, COUNT(*) AS F4
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY F1, F2, F3
```